# indentation error in eslint,es6

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, webpack-dev-server, eslint

the es6 code syntax as below,

```
import React from 'react';

const App = ({ children }) => {
    let childrenData;
    if (children) {
        childrenData = (<div>{children}</div>);
    }
    return childrenData;
};

export default App;
```

Error in eslint

```
  5:2  error  Expected indentation of 4 space character but found 0  indent
  6:2  error  Expected indentation of 4 space character but found 0  indent
  7:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space character but found 0  indent
  9:2  error  Expected indentation of 4 space character but found 0  indent
```

and my rule engine looks like this ,

```
"indent": [2, 4, {'SwitchCase': 1}],
"max-len": ["error", 200, 4],
"object-shorthand": ["error", "always", { "ignoreConstructors": true }],
"one-var": ["error", {
  "var": "always", // Exactly one var declaration per function
  "let": "always", // Exactly one let declaration per block
  "const": "never" // Exactly one declarator per const declaration per block
}],
```

can you please help me where am i wrong???

Comment: And for sure the errors are about that file?

Comment: Are you using tabs by accident?

Comment: yeah from file only ... no tabs ..

Comment: what version of eslint are you using? Also you can test your code here also against the latest eslint version. http://eslint.org/demo/

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Switchcase is in between single quotes, it should be between double as this is a JSON file.